# Using a PHP if statement

Tags: php, html

I have a feature on my website where users can create an album to organize their photos better. They can upload new photos or they can select from photos they have already uploaded.
In my PHP I have code that goes through the files they uploaded, if they uploaded any new ones. It works great, but I only want it to work when they ACTUALLY upload NEW photos. Right now, it runs even if they selected already uploaded, old photos. I am using the HTML5 "multiple" attribute so they can upload multiple photos. In my PHP, how can I write a conditional if statement to only run this code when they upload photos?

```
foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $key => $file) {
   $time= time();
   $target= UPLOADPATH . $time . $file;
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$key], $target);
}
```

I have tried using:

```
if ($_FILES['uploads']['size'] != 0)
if ($_FILES != 0)
if ($_FILES['upload']['name'] !=0)
```

But, so far no success. What can I do? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I ended up setting a variable to the value of the first element in the $_FILES array.

Like so:

```
$file_test= $_FILES['uploads']['size']['0'];
```

Then I used it in the test condion:

```
($file_test != 0) { 
    // run the code;
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help!!

Comment: `if (! empty($_FILES))` should do the trick.

Comment: `empty()` doesn't work on files. The `enctype` includes it in the post, regardless if it has bytes or not.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Then what can I do?

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES['uploads']['size']);`

Comment: @user1759682 just to clarify, do you want to compare sent files to already uploaded files to see if the ones provided are different?

Comment: Not in this scenario. I just want to see if the are uploading new ones or selecting old one, or both.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you store the already uploaded photos anywhere, then you could use a combination of `getimagesize()` function [(PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to check whether the uploaded file is an image or not. And then compare the MD5 hash of the uploaded files using the `md5_file()` function [(PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) with the ones stored. If they are stored in a database it might be a performance increase to directly store the MD5 of each file in a field for itself, so you can easily query the database for existing MD5 hash.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First your have to rearrange your $_FILES array using this function

```
function rearrange( $arr ){
        foreach($arr as $key => $items){
            foreach($items as $i => $val){
                $array[$i][$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        return $array;
}

$files = rearrange($_FILES['uploads']);

//Then do the foreach loop upload

if(!empty($files))
{

    foreach ($files as $file) {
     // Check the file size inside the foreach loop
     if($file['size'] > 0)
     {
       $time= time();
       $target= UPLOADPATH . $time . $file['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target);
     }
    }

}
```

Comment: The name attribute of your input tag must be uploads[]

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    // you've got files?!?!
}
```

Lucky guess here, don't really understand your question.

Comment: @AlienWebguy If no file is uploaded, $_FILES is an empty array. I don't get the question probably...